# Prove that the free term of the polynomial $f (x)$ is equal to $f (0)$.

Tags: polynomials

If I understand correctly, I use this formula $f(x)= a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + a_2x^{n-2} + a_{n-2}x^2 + a_{n-1}x +a_n $ and assign the variable $x = 0$.

$f(0)=a_00^n + a_10^{n-1} + a_20^{n-2} + a_{n-2}0^2 + a_{n-1}0 + a_n$

Then I get this $f(0)=a_n $ But this is a free member of the polynomial.

I right solved ?

Comment: Your algebra is correct. That term is called the "constant term", not the "free term".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is to find $f(0)$, then according to you formula, $$f(0)=a_n$$

This is Like when you have: $$g(x)=3x^{2}+5x+7$$

$$g(0)=3(0^{2})+5(0)+7=7$$